# Is it possible to pass Path arguments into FastAPI dependency functions?

Tags: python, fastapi

Is there anyway for a FastAPI "dependency" to interpret Path parameters?

I have a lot of functions of the form:

```py
@app.post("/item/{item_id}/process", response_class=ProcessResponse)
async def process_item(item_id: UUID, session: UserSession = Depends(security.user_session)) -> ProcessResponse:
    item = await get_item(client_id=session.client_id, item_id=item_id)
    await item.process()
```

Over and over, I need to pass in [multiple] arguments to fetch the required item before doing something with it.  This is very repetitive and makes the code very verbose.  What I'd really like to do is pass the `item` in as an argument to the method.

Ideally I'd like to make `get_item` a dependency or embed it somehow in the router. This would dramatically reduce the repetitive logic and excessively verbose function arguments.  The problem is that some critical arguments are passed by the client in the Path.

Is it possible to pass Path arguments into a dependency or perhaps execute the dependency in the router and pass the result?

Comment: You can make your dependency depend on a path parameter, effectively doing `Depends(item_for_client_from_path)` and having `item_for_client_from_path` depend on `item_for_client_from_path(item_id=Path(), session=Depends(security.user_session)); i.e. you make dependencies that abstract away those subdependencies that you use each time. Does that match what you're looking for?

Comment: @MatsLindh it might.  from your comment I can't see how you would extract the *parameter* from the `Path()`.  I'm new(ish) to FastAPI so I most likely missed something obvious.  As in the example above I need to extract a part of the path which may not be in an entirely uniform position.  For some functions there may be other items before `/item/{item_id}/` ... `/foo/bar/item/{item_id}/`.

Comment: As long as the parameter is named `item_id` in both locations it'll work as you expect. I'll try to make an example when I have time

Comment: That'd be awesome thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A FastAPI dependency function can take any of the arguments that a normal endpoint function can take.

So in a normal endpoint you might define a path parameter like so:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(item_id):
    return {"item_id": item_id}
```

Now if you want to use that parameter in a dependency, you can simply do:

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

async def my_dependency_function(item_id: int):
    return {"item_id": item_id}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(item_id: int, my_dependency: dict = Depends(my_dependency_function)):
    return my_dependency
```

The parameters will simply be passed on through to the dependency function if they are present there. You can also use things like `Path` and `Query` within the dependency function to define where these are coming from.

It will just analyze the request object to pull these values.

Here is an example using the `Path` function from FastAPI:

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Path

app = FastAPI()

async def my_dependency_function(item_id: int = Path(...)):
    return {"item_id": item_id}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(my_dependency: dict = Depends(my_dependency_function)):
    return my_dependency
```

As for your concern of implementing it as a dependency in the router, you can do something like this when creating the router:

```py
items_router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/items",
    tags=["items"],
    dependencies=[Depends(my_dependency_function)],
)
```

Or you can do it when you run `include_router` on the app like:

```py
app.include_router(
    items_router,
    prefix="/items",
    dependencies=[Depends(my_dependency_function)],
)
```

For more on dependencies and more examples like this see https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/

Comment: That's really great thanks. Regarding doing it on the router, I thought the return value of dependencies defined like that discarded.  Obviously I can make the dependency function attach the result to `Request.state`.  I was just wondering if I'd missed a more elegant approach.

Comment: Oh, no wait.  I think [this](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/424#issuecomment-584169213) explains how.  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: What if `my_dependency_function` needs another parameters like a database service?

Comment: @maudev Well ideally you would have a dependency function which creates a database connection, at which point just call that function from within whatever dependency needs it. That is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

There is also possibility to achieve the same via class based approach

First, Create your dependency like so

```
class ItemIdExtractor:
    async def __call__(self, item_id: int = Path()) -> int | None:
        # DO SOMETHING HERE IF NEEDED. MAYBE VALIDATE ETC.
        return item_id


ItemIdDep = Depends(ItemIdExtractor())
```

Then you can use it in any path operation you want

```
@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def retrieve_item(item_id: int = ItemIdDep):
    print(item_id)
    return Response(status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```